# Convert Class<Object> to Class<Interface>

Tags: c#, instance

I have a class `Dog` implementing an interface `IAnimal` and an `IDbSet<Dog> DogSet`.

I have the following prototype : `MyMethod(IDbSet<IAnimal> AnimalSet)`

When trying to do `MyMethod(DogSet);` I have an error at compilation saying it's not possible to explicitly cast `IDbSet<Dog>` to `IDbSet<IAnimal>`

If I try to cast it using `MyMethod((IDbSet<IAnimal>)DogSet)`, I have an error at runtime because it fails to cast.

Why can't I cast it since `Dog` implement `IAnimal` ?

Code :

```
public interface IAnimal{
    public String Libelle { get; }
}

public partial class Dog : IAnimal{
    public String Libelle {
        get {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}

// Can't convert from 'System.Data.Entity.IDbset<Models.Dog>' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<Interfaces.IAnimal>'
public abstract MyClass : MyAbstractClass{
    public MyClass(IModel dbContext) : base(dbContext, dbContext.DOG_IDBSET) { }
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
    public MyAbstractClass(Imodel dbContext, IDbSet<IAnimal>){ }
}
```

Edited code :

```
// Can't convert from 'System.Data.Entity.IDbset<Models.Dog>' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<T>'
public abstract MyClass<T> : MyAbstractClass<T> where T : Dog, IAnimal
{
    public MyClass(IModel dbContext) : base(dbContext, dbContext.DOG_IDBSET) { }
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> where T : Dog, IAnimal
{
    public MyAbstractClass(Imodel dbContext, IDbSet<T>){ }
}
```

Comment: Code please....

Comment: Inside `MyMethod`, I write `AnimalSet.Add(new Elephant())`. You `DogSet` now contains an elephant. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What you describe should work, as a Dog is a type of IAnimal.  When you say that Dog implements IAnimal, does the code say `class Dog: IAnimal`, or do you just mean that it has the same methods and properties that the interface requires?  In the latter case, you haven't implemented the interface; you just happen to have similar properties.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - no, it *shouldn't* work. Just because two types, `D` and `I` exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that does not mean that a generic, `G`, parameterized by those two types (`G<D>` and `G<I>`) exhibits the *same* relationship. (Outside of some limited co/contravariance support)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agree that you can't call something expecting `Dog` with code containing `IAnimal`, but that's not the case here; `Dog` inherits from `IAnimal` / this is the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I added code.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - but they're trying to combine *generics* and inheritance in a way that doesn't work. An `ISomething<Dog>` is *not* an `ISomething<IAnimal>`, in general, and doesn't exhibit the same relationship that `Dog` does to `IAnimal`. (If `ISomething`'s type parameter is marked `in` or `out`, it could be, but that's not true for `TEnitity` in the case of `IDbSet`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Apologies; just proved myself wrong / you right... Will have to go read up on this as I don't really understand it...

Comment: @JohnLBevan - well, look for the example I gave in my first comment for what *could* be written inside `MyMethod` if this had compiled.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever; that example does make things clear now that I actually think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to require a class implementing interface IAnimal you should be able to do this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(DbSet<T> animals) where T : class, IAnimal
{
    ...
}
```

...and call as:

```
MyMethod(DogSet);
```

Comment: I hae edited my code to reflect the change, however it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: What does it not fix? What is the problem?

Comment: It worked by adding an explicit cast : `base(dbContext, (DbSet<T>)(dbContext.DOG_IDBSET))` (at compile and runtime). I can't really get why it needs an explicit cast. For the sack of testing, I changed the abstract class into a normal class, and I didn't need the explicit cast. It seems it only wants the explicit cast if I'm using `base`.